# Mapping using reflection in Objective-c?

Tags: java, objective-c, reflection

As java developer is used to use such approach sometimes:

```
// init
Map<Class, Handler> map = new HashMap<Class, Handler>;
map.put(MyClass1.class, new Handler1());
map.put(MyClass2.class, new Handler2());

// later
Handler handler = map.get(currentObject.getClass());
handler.handle();
```

Is there similar approach in Objective-c?

PS. I know that this can probably be solved in another way: MyClass can return Handler instance (base method and overriden in inheritor), but it's not good because MyClassN does not know Handler and it can be resolved in runtime f.e.

Comment: Do you want a direct translation of this (which would be very straightforward), or are you asking about idiomatic ObjC practice?

Comment: i'm interested to know both: direct and more suitable/most used for objective-c as i understand that each language has it's own approaches  and features

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way of doing this in Objective-C is defining methods in [*Categories*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html), rather than using reflection.

A category lets you add methods to a class "from the outside", and use the method as if it were part of the class. There is no similar mechanism in Java, so you need to compensate for it by using reflection.

```
// For separate testing you can put handlers in a separate class
@interface Handlers
+(void)handler1;
+(void)handler2;
@end

// Below is the mapping code. It goes in a separate file
@interface MyClass1 (Handler)
-(void)handleMessage;
@end
@implementation MyClass1
-(void)handleMessage {
    [Handlers handler1];
}
@end
@interface MyClass2 (Handler)
-(void)handleMessage;
@end
@implementation MyClass2
-(void)handleMessage {
    [Handlers handler2];
}
@end
```

This setup lets you call `handleMessage` on objects of `MyClass1` and `MyClass2`, and the runtime will properly dispatch the message to the correct method:

```
id someObject = ...         // <<== Set an object of MyClass1 or MyClass2
[someObject handleMessage]; // Calls the right method, even though the classes themselves do not declare it
```

If you use this setup, you can test handler methods separately from the categories, which provide "glue logic" (in the same way that your Java `Map`s do) but do not participate in the actual "payload" handling of the messages.

Comment: i'm not sure that it's suitable solution. Adding category means category file code depends on ClassN code while in java solution they stay completely independent. This makes sense if taking into account modules: maven modules in java or cocoapods in obj-c. Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @4ntoine Adding a category is not any "heavier" than referencing `MyClass1.class` in Java. In fact, the mechanism behind the scene is similar to yours - Objective-C runtime keeps a hash map of "extending" methods for each class, and adds methods from categories to that has map when needed. Try this out, I think it should do the trick for you.

Comment: i mean in java solution: ClassN can be in module1, HandlerN can be in module2 and mapper can be in module3 which depends on module1 and module2. The great advantage is that they can be tested separately. Note module2 does not depend on module1 and handlers can be tested independently. In suggested category solution - is categories approach as flexible as in java (classes and handlers tested separately with no dependency between them)? Note mapping can be changed in java's solution in run-time and in categories solution - no.

Comment: @4ntoine You can organize your code in a way that lets you test handlers separately from your classes, with categories providing a "glue", and the logic sitting in some other place (in the answer above, I put the logic in class methods of the `Handler` class).

Comment: in last edited code example HandlerN "knows" about mapper (invoking concrete Handlers method). it means that "tail wags the dog" and it's completely wrong. unfortunately i can't see according solution in obj-c for now, thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: @4ntoine No, it's the other way around - it's mapper (i.e. the code with categories on ) that knows about `Handlers`. The mapping code goes in a separate file. The `Handlers` remains a self-sufficient entity that stands on its own.

Comment: ok, that seems to be more suitable but i should think a bit as i'm not obj-c guru. thanks!